# Does android:installLocation in manifest affect updates as well as fresh installs

Tags: android, installation, android-manifest

I have two questions:

1 . Does the "[android:installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)" tag in the Android manifest affect updates as well as fresh installs?

I have a published app on the market with no "android:installLocation" at all, I am thinking of adding one of the following to the manifest:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
OR
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

Could this affect users who simply update their app? Could their app be transferred to external storage?

My second question follows on assuming the answer is "yes".

2 . If an app is moved during an update, could the data associated with the app be affected? E.g. databases or shared preference files.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) says "The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory."

But I am worried that instead of the normal update, the system may perform a full uninstall/install cycle which would wipe the data. This is unacceptable in my situation.

I'm sorry that I cannot answer this question myself through experimentation however I don't have access to any devices that have external storage. Hopefully someone has done the above and can confirm the result, one way or another.

Extra info:
minSDK = 10
targetSDK = 17

Thanks for your help:

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question. Yes. It will affect updates for existing users.

> But I am worried that instead of the normal update, the system may
>   perform a full uninstall/install cycle which would wipe the data. This
>   is unacceptable in my situation.

The only time this wold happen is if you changed your signing key. It is the key that identiifies your app as unique on Google Play.

Seriously you have nothing to worry about as far as that is concerned.

Your data will stay on internal storage. This is important for security.

Problems will only really occur if you store your data on the sd card and your app on internal storage. You have to account for the fact that the data might not be available. But like I say. for your scenario. You really don't have to worry.

Comment: Thanks so much for your rapid answer. I hoped that would be the case. I just didn't want to take the chance because wiping 3000 user's saved game probably wouldn't go down well! ;)